# How to add a button to a table cell to make the button as part of the cell? Just like the Properties view of Winderbuilder

Tags: java, cell

Here is the UI of Windowbuilder: 
http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/eclipse/attachments/2900d1328496793-using-windowbuilder-design-gui-eclipse-properties-pane.png

The  Properties view is at the bottom left of the UI, you can see there is a cell with "dialog15" text and a button at its right hand.

Now I want to create such cell in my table: User can input text to the cell directly, or click the button to select the existing text in a new opened window... But I don't know how to start it. Could anyone give me a hand? Any tutorial?

BTW, I am using SWT. I found some examples using SWING, but haven't found any good tutorial using SWT

Comment: could u tell ..in what languages or tool .you want to make?

Comment: I am using Java(SWT, JFace...). I want to create a plugin.

Comment: check this link i am sure this will help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069641/adding-buttons-inside-cell-of-jtable-along-with-data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069641/adding-buttons-inside-cell-of-jtable-along-with-data)

Comment: Thanks Mayank! But this example is using Swing, any tutorial using SWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for CellEditor / Table Editor concepts in Jface table viewer.

[jface sample snippets](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFaceSnippets)

Comment: Thanks, but I there is no any tutorial meeting my requirement in the URL you provided.