# Button and Textbox alignment in a jtable cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, layout-manager, tablecellrenderer

I have a table which has both button and text box in some cells. Now I am able to put both the components in the table cell. Thanks for [OscarRyz's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069641/adding-buttons-inside-cell-of-jtable-along-with-data.) code. Now my problem is I have to align these components such that the button is to extreme right of the cell and text box should start from the extreme left of the cell  to the start of the button. (In simple, they should be adjacent to each other and occupy entire cell.) How can I align them inside the cell?

Currently it looks like this,

[image]

But what I was looking is for the view something like this,

[image]

I have looked at [Component Border](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/component-border/) code but can't figure out how to use it for the table.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `JPanel` with `BorderLayout` where you put the `JTextField` in the `BorderLayout.CENTER` and the `JButton` in the `BorderLayout.EAST` should do it.

And for future reference: bookmark the [Visual guide to layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) if you are looking for a `LayoutManager`

Comment: You mean to say that I should add jpanel to the table cell and then add both these components to that panel.

Comment: I mean that if the renderer would return a panel as described above you would obtain the desired result.

Comment: Thanks Robin .. u made me know table cells are not only for data but also for panels or may be what ever we want to insert .. :)

Comment: @Che `ClassCastException` comes from `myEditor.setCompValues((MyComponents)value);`. The values passed in that method are the values contained in your `TableModel`

Comment: But my table model contains many columns and I need to have button and text-box only for one column and my remaining columns have the data as usual. So I am using this rendering only for that column. Is this wrong way of doing? or shall I pass entire row of data and use this rendering class to fill the row data. If I am wrong please explain.

Comment: Then only make those cells editable ... then you won't enter the editor code for the other cells. But if you have extra questions, start a new one instead of asking them in the comments

Answer (score 3):

- `JPanel` has implemented `FlowLayout` then to pretty accepting the `PreferredSize` came from its childs,
- notice everything depends of your `TableCellRenderer` and `TableCellEditor` too
- [my view, my example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6355910/714968)

Comment: Thanks. I will try. It looks as it will solve my problem .. :)

Comment: don't forget to add EmtyBorders to the JPanel, in Editor and Renderer too

Comment: I have updated my post with code. I am getting a class cast exception. Please have a look and can u tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: I just want to ask one thing .. the example which you wrote is for the entire table's row. But what I have done is only for one column. Is this correct way what I am doing or shall I use the rendering for the entire row like what you have done.