# How to structure my attendance program

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jradiobutton

I'm in the process of making an application that keeps attendance. Once I have a list of students, how would I go about displaying them all and checking whether they are present or absent. I intially thought JTable would work, but it's not the easiest thing in the world to add swing components to a JTable. Is there an easier way to go about this? The image below shows roughly what I'm picturing, but if you have a different idea, feel free to share. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: _I intially thought JTable would work, but it's not the easiest thing in the world to add swing components to a JTable._ Why do you think so?

Comment: [`CheckOne`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7920159/230513) is a basic example using `JChckbox`; some `JRadioButton` alternatives are cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11173600/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Here is an EG to show how you can use `JTable`

I have kept a boolean value for `ABS/Present` coloumn, as suggested by @Hendrik Ebbers ,It will automatically come as a `CheckBox`.
First you have to set the model of your `JTabel` using `fooTable.setModel(dataModel)`,

Something like this:

```
    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {"Joel", "Hails", new Integer(1011001), new Boolean(true)},
            {"James", "Roggers", new Integer(1912212), null},
            {"Rehy", "Gomes", new Integer(1121212), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Sunil", "gawas", new Integer(9909090), null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "1st name", "last name", "ID/NUMBER", "ABS/Present"
        }
    )
```

Where in `new Object [][]` i have my all Data, and `new String []` will have the column names.

Rest you can find more info on

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Try yourself,Ask for the source code if you have any problems.

**UPDATE:**

you can try out this:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

 public class NewJFrame3 extends JPanel {

 public NewJFrame3() {
 super(new GridLayout(1,0));
 JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
 table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
 table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

 JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

 add(scrollPane);
 }
 class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
 private String[] columnNames = {"1st Name",
 "Last Name",
 "ID/NUMBER",
 "PRESENT"};
 private Object[][] data = {
 {"Joel", "Hails",
 "110023", new Boolean(false)},
 {"John", "Doe",
 "343409", new Boolean(true)},
 {"Sue", "well",
 "899800", new Boolean(false)},
 {"Jane", "White",
 "990909", new Boolean(true)},

 };
 public int getColumnCount() {
 return columnNames.length;
 }
 public int getRowCount() {
 return data.length;
 }
 public String getColumnName(int col) {
 return columnNames[col];
 }
  public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
  return data[row][col];
  }

public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
  return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
   }




 }

 private static void createAndShowGUI() {
 //Create and set up the window.
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableDemo");
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 //Create and set up the content pane.
 NewJFrame3 newContentPane = new NewJFrame3();
 newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
 frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
 //Display the window.
 frame.pack();
 frame.setVisible(true);
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {

 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
 createAndShowGUI();
 }
 });
 }
 }
```

Comment: I do have some problems. I tried doing what you did here (http://pastebin.com/u0w4tcLq). However, I got this result (http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/407/jtable.png). No titles and no rendered check boxes.

Comment: I fixed the title problem by adding the table to a scroll pane, but there are still no check boxes.

Comment: @JoelA.Christophel Please update the full source code **here**.Don't provide links for that.And have you taken tutorial?Please copy paste your full source code here(i mean as an update in your Question).

Comment: I got it to work, but how do I check/uncheck the boxes?

Comment: @JoelA.Christophel please please look at the link i gave.It covers examples

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is, use checkbox instead of two radio box controls .its look better .

And check the presented user .

Comment: This should be in a comment.

Comment: Just use a boolean value for the "present" column. The data will automatically displayed as a Checkbox. If the checkbox is not checked the student was absent

Comment: @HendrikEbbers  I think RadioButton looks promising than using CheckBox.

Comment: @Che Checkbox will come automatically if your column is Boolean,otherwise, will have to use the method given in your answer.

Comment: @joeyrohan I know that. Just write Boolean.class it will do the trick. But I am talking about the visibility. The _OP_ choice was good even it is not easy as check box.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the first 3 columns look normal. But the fourth column is what I think you got stuck at.

Read about [Renderer and Editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) in `JTable`.

I think rendering a `JPanel` to the last column will do the trick. On that `JPanel` add two `JRadioButton`'s.

One example of doing it is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069641/adding-buttons-inside-cell-of-jtable-along-with-data) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622585/button-and-textbox-alignment-in-a-jtable-cell).

**P.S:** I tried this approach, it works.

Comment: Thanks for the information. +1 I learned about Renders and Editors from your answer. However, I'm going to go with the cop-out solution provided by joey.